# С помощью одного цикла вывести даные

Tags: python

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##BcHHOgNhGIDRvav4n6xibWenRhC9eywQkVFmxswQsVKjlwSR6L33FqLdwvtd0TjHjDphQ89z3ZBhKVtpumr3FBQWFZeU@sr85RWVgarqmtq6@obGpuaW1rbOru5gT6g3rPX1Dwzqhjlk2c7wSGQ0OsYacRKss8EmSbZIkWabHXbZY58DDjnimBNOOeOcCy654pobbrnjngceeeKZF155450MH3yS5YtvfvjlT8ZlQiZlSqZlRmIyK3MyLwuyKEuyLCuy6unIz1HKtDTd8dq5rvsP)

```
for s in ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"]:
  print(s)
```

Comment: Читер, однако! )

Answer (score 2):

```
for s in for s in [*range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1), *range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1), *range(ord('А'), ord ('я') +1)]: print(chr(s))
```

Comment: О, прикольно, chain и starmap не понадобились. Впрочем, этот вариант длиннее)

Comment: Можно A-z и А-я сократить. В большинстве кодировок они подряд.

Comment: Нельзя. Они не идут подряд. По крайней мере, латинские.

Comment: Окей, откатываем)))

Comment: Надеюсь никто не будет запускать этот код на koi-8))

Comment: На 866 тоже не сработает - там кириллица где-то разрывалась псевдографикой)

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##LY09DsIwDEb3nMLKlECWig2JgWuwRU1KI1E7MkYqvQTcBI5SThT65@n7ZL/n/JSW8FBKw9RBkshCdLtD6jKxwF08dz47qFufUKkQG/AhVKa3RwXAUR6M0O8rpRri6QoSwgSYuuUNMrtNYtjjNToYUjZzJQ4O9NmP7/GrrVuw2b2mdXsZxs/vpe0y88fMCWWyO4gYTlrbUv4)

```
from itertools import starmap, chain

def add1(x):
  return x+1

for ch in map(chr, chain(*starmap(range, zip(map(ord, "AaАа"), map(add1, map(ord, "ZzЯя")))))):
  print(ch, end="")
```

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##LYxBDsIgFET3nOKHFVVi0rhz5zXckUIFI3zy@01qL6E30aPgidDazmoyM2/ynT2mfa09YYTAjhjxOkCIGYlhYEPRZA2dNyEJYV0PxtpWjc1BAJDjGyUYt60QmUJiJeXugiGpH6Q6TyuoNuuRIpPOTsMU8n@CZDXIoynP8paNhjmb/xe3tKepvD4P2ayq9Qs)

```
from itertools import starmap, chain

def add1(x):
  return x+1

print("".join(map(chr, chain(*starmap(range, zip(map(ord, "AaАа"), map(add1, map(ord, "ZzЯя"))))))))
```

Comment: Map считается циклом

Comment: @eri, кем считается? То, что он внутри содержит цикл, не означает, что он считается циклом.

Comment: Мной считается)

Comment: @eri ну тогда и range нужно считать циклом )

Comment: @CrazyElf, range - точно не цикл - он лишь создаёт итератор.

Comment: @CrazyElf но range не выполняет пользовательский код